# Akka.Net: Transparently Passing Along Contextual Information for Auditing/Authorization

Tags: authorization, akka, audit, akka.net

### Background

We have very strict auditing requirements and want to be able to correlate every action our system takes on behalf of the user to a specific authentication operation (sign-on). In addition to these strict auditing requirements, we also have some complex authorization requirements unsolvable by simple claims based authorization.

Considering both of these together led me to wondering the feasibility of using an 'envelope' type design, where messages sent stemming from a user request are wrapped in an envelope containing the necessary information, such as their auth token and info about the sending machine. Now, it would be fairly simple enough to add a property for this token to every message, but that seems tacky and since its a rather cross-cutting concern, I would rather it not pollute every protocol in the system, which is why I'm thinking the envelope idea is worth considering. This approach would also require the cooperation of every actor in the system and my goal is to have this be transparent to actors who don't need any of this information, but also make the information available in case actors do need it. In the case of actors needing it, it's also OK if they just accept the envelope type directly.

---

### Imagined Solution

#### Overview

- Wrap each `Tell` operation in an envelope used to transport required contextual information

  - Perhaps implemented w/ a custom actor ref provider and actor ref wrapping the ones configured
- Unwrap envelope, if exists, on each receive operation

  - Custom mailbox

    - Would also handle sending a message to the auditing service
  - How to make the contextual information available to the actor?

    - Can we add to the actor's `Context` object somehow?
    - Also acceptable for actor to accept the envelope type/not use custom mailbox in this case

---

#### Discussion

In order to make this all transparent, my initial thinking is to 'intercept' the send/receive operations. I understand enough akka.net to implement a custom mailbox and I think this would be the way to go for this kind of approach, but I'm open to other ideas. The mailbox would perform the unwrap and make the contextual information available to the actor in case it's required (99% of the time it's not, likely better to just accept the envelope directly when it is required to be explicit). The mailbox would also handle fulfilling the auditing requirement by sending a message to the auditing service w/ the required information, which not only includes the contextual information from the request, but also local machine information to know where/who did the processing.

The part I'm second guessing myself on is intercepting the send operation (`Tell`). Since `IActorRef` instances are created via a configured `IActorRefProvider` and since this guy handles the `Tell` operation (via it's created `IActorRef` instances), I think it makes sense to write a custom `IActorRefProvider` and a custom `IActorRef`. Both would wrap the implementations that are configured (decorator pattern), and the custom `IActorRef` would provide the required behavior in it's `Tell` method. For webapi apps (only entry point for users), it would pull the required contextual information from `HttpContext` (one custom ref provider) and for backend apps (another custom ref provider), it would pull the required contextual information from the current message's context. I'm not sure how to add data to the actor's `Context` property, but I'm assuming it is possible.

With these two pieces in place, the contextual information would effectively be passed along, from actor to actor, and service to service. So even if a message is 20 actors down the line, if it was initially instigated by a user via the REST API, it would still have that contextual information, thereby allowing a full and complete audit and tracing of each action our system takes back to a specific sign on.

---

### What I'm Hoping For

The primary thing I'm hoping for with this post is validation that this is a reasonable approach to take, and if not, why not and alternate suggestions for achieving the desired behavior. Also very welcomed would be any code samples for custom mailboxes/actor ref/actor ref providers and extra cookies if they're doing something similar to what I'm trying to accomplish here. Another welcomed tidbit is how to do the mailbox configuration so I don't need to manually update all of my `Props` with the custom mailbox implementation. Akka.net configuration is definitely a weaker point of mine, particularly the deployments section, so any core knowledge/articles/advice here is greatly appreciated!

Thanks for taking the time to read this! Any and all help is ***much*** appreciated!

---

### Other StackOverflow Issues:

The answers provided in these issues require the cooperation of every actor. Ideally this is all transparent and actors that don't need to use this contextual information can be written as if it didn't exist.

- [Passing Contextual Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510695/passing-contextual-information)
- [How to elegantly log contextual information along with every message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358708/how-to-elegantly-log-contextual-information-along-with-every-message)

There were a couple others I viewed [can't find them right now for some reason], but they all either required cooperation or global shared state [isn't that what akka avoids? :p]

Answer (score 1):

[Phobos, a proprietary observability library for Akka.NET](https://phobos.petabridge.com/), wraps all messages inside a distributed tracing context - which can be aggregated back together again in an off-the-shelf tracing system that supports [OpenTracing](https://opentracing.io/), such as Jaeger / Zipkin / Azure Application Insights.

You can append custom data to each of the traces that are captured inside your actors via the [`Context.GetInstrumentation()` method](https://phobos.petabridge.com/api/Phobos.Actor.PhobosActorContextExtensions.html#Phobos_Actor_PhobosActorContextExtensions_GetInstrumentation_Akka_Actor_IActorContext_) inside any of your actors' - custom data can include tags that might include a unique userId, a transaction Id, and so on. That's all part of the OpenTracing specification.

Disclosure: I work for Petabridge, the makers of Phobos. It's proprietary and costs money to use, but it's purpose built to offer this type of decentralized, but complete tracing out of the box.

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use Phobos you might be able to accomplish this using a custom messaging protocol for context propagation and structured logging with the Akka.Logger.Serilog library.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. We're going to end up using Phobos, so thanks for including that! I didn't even think about using Phobos for this (haven't gotten a license just yet). Does this mean my original idea is not possible or just isn't the best approach in your opinion? From an academic standpoint, I'm curious if intercepting tell/receive is feasible via custom actor ref&provider and custom mailbox.

Comment: Intercepting the tell via a custom `IActorRefProvider` is definitely possible - that's how we built Phobos! But it comes with a lot of strings attached and edge cases you need to worry about. You're probably better off creating a generic `ActorBase` sub class that overrides `AroundReceive` and intercepting that way, even though it's not as aspect-oriented.